# Best road route from Córdoba to Mendoza, Argentina?

Tags: driving, routes, argentina, hitchhiking

When travelling west across Argentina from Córdoba towards Mendoza, which is the best route to take? In terms of road quality, speed limits and most used.

My friends and I are looking to hitch hike and would like to know the routes that are most suitable and why. 
I have had a look at the [hitch wiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Cordoba_(Argentina)) for Córdoba but it contradicts my original thoughts of going south towards Río Cuarto first and then west.

Comment: @pnuts Which route?

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, there is no best, just different. Hitching rides is a Chilean cultural norm; any route offers opportunity. @pnuts is on holiday, I'm a poor substitute, but agree your initial plan of going south and west works.

The most expeditious driving route is along RN 36, making your way out of Córdoba along Av. Velez Sarsfield toward the southwest. It becomes RN 36 outside of the city itself. At Río Cuarto, you go from RN A005, then Ruta 20 in General Pedernera, picking up RN 7 and on to Mendoza. There are lots of little jigs and jogs, but plenty of chances to stop, eat, rest, and interact with the warm and welcoming Chilenos.

For routes on which local buses run from town to town, look at RN 148 or RU 20 and onto 146 (just after El Pantanillo), working your way south to San Luis and to the RU7 and on to Mendoza. Continuing on RU20, although it runs west, may be less desirable: towns are more dispersed, and you'd have to get to RU 142 to make your way toward Mendoza.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand what Chilean culture and people have to do with hitchhiking in Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and safest is Córdoba->Rio Cuarto->Villa Mercedes->San Luis->Mendoza

It includes some highways.

The scenic one is Córdoba->Merlo->San Luis->Mendoza.
Inside Cordoba, you need to take RP34: Cordoba->Carlos Paz--RP14--RP34--Mina Clavero->Merlo